# Exporting from Google Earth Engine into Google Earth Pro

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

I've found a dataset ([Link Here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WCMC_WDPA_current_points)) that I would like to export into Google Earth Pro so that I can analyse it alongside other data. Is this possible for me to do?

I'm sorry if the question has a simple answer but I have next to no experience with coding - I just need the dataset into a file that could be imported into Google Earth Pro. I can't seem to find any simple export button and a google search seems to suggest there's some way of coding an export? But this is totally beyond me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to export the data, you'll first need to apply for access to Earth Engine, which you can do using the Sign Up button in the upper right corner of https://earthengine.google.com.

Once you have access, the data can be exported with just a few lines of code, e.g.

```
var points = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/points');

Export.table.toDrive({
  features: points,
  folder: 'GEE_exports',
  fileFormat: 'KMZ'
});
```

This snippet will attempt to export the dataset as a KMZ file to a folder in your Google Drive called `GEE_exports` and will fail if it can't find that folder. For all the available options, including other file formats, check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting) or the [Export documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#export.table.todrive).

Once you run the code, you can monitor the status of the export in the Task tab (found in the right panel of the Earth Engine code editor). Depending on the size of the dataset, it may be necessary to break it up into smaller regions and run a few different exports.